# Capistrano Deployment: git-checkout-index: unable to write file, cannot create directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am new to deploying rails websites using capistrano.

I pushed my changes to the git repository **successfully** without getting any error.
Now I need to push the same changes to the production server using Capistrano.

When I run `cap deploy`  I get the following error:

```
urjit@urjit-Lenovo:~/workspace/dev$ cap deploy    
  * executing `deploy'    
  * executing `deploy:update'    
 ** transaction: start    
  * executing `deploy:update_code'    
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:devrepublicrep/devcockpit.git HEAD"
/usr/bin/git     
  * executing "git clone -q git@github.com:devrepublicrep/devcockpit.git      /home/devcockpit/releases/20120820062500 && cd /home/devcockpit/releases/20120820062500 && git checkout -q -b deploy c51262dbb81a66f307127c85add0786552c03cad && (echo c51262dbb81a66f307127c85add0786552c03cad >       /home/devcockpit/releases/20120820062500/REVISION)"    
    servers: ["dev.devrepublic.nl"]      
Password: 
    [dev.devrepublic.nl] executing command      
 ** [dev.devrepublic.nl :: err] error: git-checkout-index: unable to write file      public/javascripts/ckeditor/_source/plugins/embed/dialogs/embed.js        
 ** [dev.devrepublic.nl :: err] fatal: cannot create directory at public/javascripts/ckeditor/_source/skins/v2/images       
 ** [dev.devrepublic.nl :: err] fatal: Untracked working tree file '.gitignore' would be overwritten by merge.      
    command finished       
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/devcockpit/releases/20120820062500; true"       
    servers: ["dev.devrepublic.nl"]      
    [dev.devrepublic.nl] executing command      
    command finished       
failed: "sh -c 'git clone -q git@github.com:devrepublicrep/devcockpit.git       /home/devcockpit/releases/20120820062500 && cd /home/devcockpit/releases/20120820062500 && git checkout -q -b deploy c51262dbb81a66f307127c85add0786552c03cad && (echo c51262dbb81a66f307127c85add0786552c03cad > /home/devcockpit/releases/20120820062500/REVISION)'" on dev.devrepublic.nl
```

Please Help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer need to clean up some space.

so I ran **cap deploy:cleanup** command.